# ZF2 with PhlyRestfully the json response is reflecting the entity structure

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using PhlyRestfully to develop a web based API that has the business logic(Services, Entities...) in other module. In order to do that I've created a module named "Api" that has configured the PhlyRestfully to use the hydrator `ClassMethods`. The issue is that my entity has a lot for proprieties and the api response is reflecting the entity and I don't want that.

For example  my entity has the proprieties :

```
class Deal {
   $deal_id;
   $title;
   $description;
   $price;
}
```

The fetch method created in Model/Service is returning a Deal but it selects only the title and deal_id because these are only columns that I want to display in the response. The response doesn't have only the title and deal_id as I wanted but is reflecting the hole entity. If I'm not specifying the hydrator in the config the response is how I wanted (wih  title and deal_id) but there is another problem in response, the key has an additional text("\u0000*\u0000).From what I saw in the code the additional text is added because of the cast and a hydrator is necessary.

There is any solution to resolve this problem without build a separate logic in the "Api" module? Can someone suggest me any other solutions ?

**Resource:**

```
namespace Api\Resources;

class Deals extends AbstractListenerAggregate
{

    protected $listeners = array();

    protected $table;

    public function __construct($table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('create', array($this, 'onCreate'));
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('fetch', array($this, 'onFetch'));
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('fetchAll', array($this, 'onFetchAll'));
    }

    public function onCreate(ResourceEvent $e)
    {
        $data  = $e->getParam('data');
        $paste = $this->table->save($data);
        if (!$paste) {
            throw new CreationException();
        }
        return $paste;
    }

    public function onFetch(ResourceEvent $e)
    {
        $id = $e->getParam('id');
        $paste = $this->table->getDealMapper()->fetchById($id);
        $paste->addresses = new HalResource(array('deals'), 1);
        if (!$paste) {
            throw new DomainException('Paste not found', 404);
        }
        return $paste;
    }

    public function onFetchAll(ResourceEvent $e)
    {
        // getDealsApi is selecting only the deal_id and the title
        $deals = $this->table->getDealMapper()->getDealsApi();
        foreach($deals as $deal) {

            $deal->categories = array(
                '3' => array(
                    'name' => 'asdasd', 
                    'href' => 'url'
                )
            );
        }

        return $deals;
    }
}
```

**Entity from the "Common" module:**

```
namespace Common\Entity;

class Deal
{
    protected $deal_id;

    protected $store_id;

    protected $title;

    protected $short_description;

    protected $list_price;

    protected $price;

    protected $discount;

    protected $discount_type;

    protected $image_url;

    protected $link;


    /**
     * @return dealId
     */
    public function getDealId()
    {
        return $this->deal_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param $dealId
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDealId($dealId)
    {
        $this->deal_id = (int) $dealId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return store_id
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->store_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param $storeId
     * @return self
     */
    public function setStoreId($storeId)
    {
        $this->store_id = $storeId;
        return $this;
    }

     /**
     * @return title
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param $title
     * @return self
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return shortDescription
     */
    public function getShortDescription()
    {
        return $this->short_description;
    }

    /**
     * @param $description
     * @return self
     */
    public function setShortDescription($description)
    {
        $this->short_description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return link
     */
    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }

    /**
     * @param $link
     * @return self
     */
    public function setLink($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;
        return $this;
    }     

    /**
     * @return list_price
     */
    public function getListPrice()
    {
        return $this->list_price;
    }

    /**
     * @param $listPrice
     * @return self
     */
    public function setListPrice($listPrice)
    {
        $this->list_price = $listPrice;
        return $this;
    }   

    /**
     * @return price
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param $price
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
        return $this;
    }   

    /**
     * @return discount
     */
    public function getDiscount()
    {
        return $this->discount;
    }

    /**
     * @param $discount
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDiscount($discount)
    {
        $this->discount = $discount;
        return $this;
    }   

    /**
     * @return discount_type
     */
    public function getDiscountType()
    {
        return $this->discount_type;
    }

    /**
     * @param $discounType
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDiscountType($discounType)
    {
        $this->discount_type = $discounType;
        return $this;
    }   

    /**
     * @return image_url
     */
    public function getImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->image_url;
    }

    /**
     * @param $imageUrl
     * @return self
     */
    public function setImageUrl($imageUrl)
    {
        $this->image_url = $imageUrl;
        return $this;
    }   
}
```

**Api module config:**

```
<?php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Api\Controller\Index' => 'Api\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'api' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/api',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Api\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                      //  'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'deals' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/deals[/[:id]]',
                            // 'controller' => 'Api\Controller\Deals',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Api\Controller\Deals',
                            ),

                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy'
        ),
    ),
    'phlyrestfully' => array(
        'resources' => array(
            'Api\Controller\Deals' => array(
                'listener' => 'Api\Resource\Deal',
                'route_name' => 'api/deals',
                'resource_http_options'   => array('get'),
                'page_size' => 1,  
            )
        ),
        'renderer' => array(
            'hydrators' => array(
                'Common\Entity\Deal' =>'Hydrator\ClassMethods',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Hydrator\ClassMethods' => 'Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods',
        ),
    ),    
);
```

**The response using this code :**

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://deal.local.com/api/deals?page=1"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://deal.local.com/api/deals"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://deal.local.com/api/deals?page=1"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "deal_id": 1,
                "type": null,
                "store_id": null,
                "title": "Title of the deal",
                "short_description": null,
                "long_description": null,
                "status": null,
                "slug": null,
                "link": null,
                "list_price": null,
                "price": null,
                "discount": null,
                "discount_type": null,
                "image_url": null,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From what you can see it sets NULL for the keys that are not returned by the getDealsApi()

**And I want to look like this:**

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://deal.local.com/api/deals?page=1"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://deal.local.com/api/deals"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://deal.local.com/api/deals?page=1"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "deal_id": 1,
                "title": "Title of the deal",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should do like this:

$deals = $this->table->getDealMapper()->getDealsApi();
$a = array(); 
foreach($deals as $deal) {

    $deal->categories = array(
     '3' => array(
             'name' => 'asdasd', 
            'href' => 'url'
       )
    );
    $a[] = $deal;
}
$deals = $a
```